# Two-dimensional array of 0s & 1s, sliced and keys returned as set in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a number of records in a text file that represent days of a 'month' 1-30 and whether a shop is open or closed. The letters represent the shop.

```
    A 00000000001000000000000000000
    B 11000000000000000000000000000
    C 00000000000000000000000000000
    D 00000000000000000000000000000
    E 00000000000000000000000000000
    F 00000000000000000000000000000
    G 00000000000000000000000000000
    H 00000000000000000000000000000
    I 11101111110111111011111101111
    J 11111111111111111111111111111
    K 00110000011000001100000110000
    L 00010000001000000100000010000
    M 00100000010000001000000100000
    N 00000000000000000000000000000
    O 11011111101111110111111011111
```

I want to store the 1's and 0's as is in an array (I'm thinking numpy but there is a another way (string, bitstring) I'd be happy with that). Then I want to be able to slice one day , i.e a column and get the record keys back in a set.

e.g.

```
A 1
B 0
C 0
D 0
E 0
F 0
G 0
H 0
I 0
J 1
K 1
L 1
M 0
N 0
O 1

day10 = {A,J,K,L,O}
```

I also need this to be as performant as absolutely possible.

Comment: I don't think having to be able to run "thousands of times an hour" for a task like imply you need particularly performant code. A very naive algorithm (string.index) will probably yield thousands of these *each second* on modern hardware

Comment: You need to generate the datastructure thousands of times or query it thousands of times?

Comment: @goncalopp actually this will be part of an algorithm that is performed 20 million times an hour so I don't want to augment that algo with anything more than a few usecs

Comment: Your array also has the character 'l' in it... does this mean something different from the integer 1?

Comment: @JLLagrange no sorry, that's a copy/paste screwup. Sorted

Comment: If you need such extreme performance, you may want to consider writing this in a lower level language. Something tells me that, since your queries are small, even using numpy the amount of overhead in function calls and interpretation will probably be greater than the actual calculation itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 with open("datafile") as f:
    for line in f:
        shop, _days = line.split()
        for i,d in enumerate(_days):
            if d == '1':
                days[i].add(shop)
```

Simpler, faster and answers the question

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution I've come up with:

```
shops = {}
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, month = line.strip().split()
        shops[name] = [d == '1' for d in month]

dayIndex = 14

result = [s for s,v in shops.iteritems() if v[dayIndex]]
print "Shops opened at",dayIndex,":",result
```

Comment: This is faster than my numpy implementation. It'll be even faster if you change `shops.items()` to `shops.iteritems()` in the `result` line.

Comment: @askewchan Thanks for sharing this information, that's very interesting! I've also incorporated your hint into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A numpy solution:

```
stores, isopen = np.genfromtxt('input.txt', dtype="S30", unpack=True)
isopen = np.array(map(list, isopen)).astype(bool)
```

Then,

```
>>> stores[isopen[:,10]]
array(['A', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'O'], 
      dtype='|S30')
```

Comment: Very nice one! Overlooked that approach as I tend to have all data in one object.

Comment: @alko, It's difficult to expand the string to a list if you keep it as a structured array (which is what I tried first).

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("datafile") as fin:
    D = {i[0]:int(i[:1:-1], 2) for i in fin}
days = [{k for k in D if D[k] & 1<<i} for i in range(31)]
```

Just keep the `days` variable between queries

Comment: would you mind explaining how this works? It does but I don't get it!

Comment: `D` is a dictionary mapping the shops to a [bitmask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)). It's fairly easy to scan through the bitmasks to create the list of sets

Answer (score 1):

First, I would hesitate to write the amount of code to make things work for example for [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/).

Second, I already upvoted BartoszKP's answer as it looks like a reasonable approach.

Last, I would use pandas instead of numpy for such a task, as for most tasks it will use underlying numpy functions and will reasonable fast.

If `data` contains your array as string, converting to DataFrame can be done with

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[x] +  map(int, y) 
...             for x, y in [l.split() for l in data.splitlines()]])
>>> df.columns = ['Shop'] + map(str, range(1, 30))
```

and lookups are done with

```
>>> df[df['3']==1]['Shop']
8     I
9     J
10    K
12    M
Name: Shop, dtype: object
```

Comment: pandas is a great suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Use a multilayered dictionary:

```
all_shops = { 'shopA': { 1: True, 2: False, 3: True ...},
              .......}
```

Then your query is translated to

```
def query(shop_name, day):
    return all_shops[shop_name][day]
```

Comment: Doesn't this only tell me if one shop is open. Not which shops are open on a given day?

Comment: *[shop for shop in all_shops if query(shop, day_no)]*. You may also build reverse dictionary - day_to_shops - *opened = {1: set(['shopA', 'shopB']), ...}*